# How do I represent -9223372036854775808 in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

-9223372036854775808 is the most negative int64_t. the problem is that if I use `-9223372036854775808L` or `-9223372036854775808LL` then I get the warning "integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned". The issue is that the `-` is being treated separately and positive 9223372036854775808 is indeed too big for int64_t. If I try `-9223372036854775808UL` then I get the warning "unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned". How do I properly encode this number?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()`

Comment: `L` for `long` and `LL` for `long long`.

Comment: Also note that the actual bit-width of almost all types are expressed as minimums in the specifications. `long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, but could be 64 bits (or more), and `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits (or more).

Comment: You can also use LLONGMIN in #include <limits.h>.

Comment: I updated the question: LL produces the same warning as L

Comment: Note for mods: this question is different than linked questions because this is about hardcoding a constant which is at the max range of native representation. This is unique from the other questions since LL isnt enough to actually properly represent the number.

Comment: Just use `INT64_MIN` defined in `stdint.h` (`cstdint` in C++).

Comment: It's a classic mistake to think C or C++ have negative integer constants. The `-` is an _operator_ applied to the non-negative number - it is not part of the number when written out in the source like this.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, I see that...but it seems wrong from a language design perspective to do that, right? After all, the number is a representable constant that the assembly can handle, but instead of that the compiler authors turn it into a mathematical operation, why?

Comment: @nielsen that seems to be the same question that I'm asking, thanks. IDK why that didnt come up in my search....Could that link be added to the list at the top?

Comment: @chacham15 Not sure why - probably out of historical reasons or because C supports various exotic signed formats. I added the link to the duplicate list as per your request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the literal -9223372036854775808 is being treated as a positive number because it's outside the range of a signed 64-bit integer. To properly represent this number in your code, you can use the LL suffix to indicate a long long integer, and also use the unary minus operator to make it negative. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int64_t myInt = -9223372036854775807LL - 1LL;
    cout<<myInt; // prints -9223372036854775808
    return 0;
}
```

By subtracting 1 from -9223372036854775807LL, you effectively obtain the minimum representable value of int64_t. The use of LL ensures that the literal is treated as a long long integer. This approach avoids the issues with interpretation as an unsigned type or exceeding the range of signed integers.

Comment: This does work, but is there no way to actually represent the minimum number as a hardcoded int64?

Comment: In the syntax of C++, `-9223372036854775807LL` is the combination of the unary `-` operator and the `9223372036854775807LL` literal. Even for the simple case as `-1`, it is not a literal in the language, but is instead combination of `-` and the literal `1`. The understanding in OP's question is correct.

Comment: I just checked the implementation of `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` on my machine: `return -__LONG_MAX__ - 1;`. So essentially the same as this answer.

Comment: @chacham15 You are supposed to use `INT64_MIN`/`... ::min()`. Also you could reverse-engineer the macro a bit: https://godbolt.org/z/c9rYEa4d3. As you can see the macro is defined as `(-9223372036854775807L-1)` on this particular target (gcc 64 bit Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `LL` for `long long` which is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits:

```
-9223372036854775807LL-1
```

You might also need to subtract one in case `9223372036854775808` does not fit in `long long` and therefore cannot exist to be negated with unary `-`.